# Path to CKEditor in CakePHP app on Zeus server

Tags: url-rewriting, ckeditor, cakephp-2.0

I'm integrating CKEditor into a CakePHP app which is running on a Zeus server (and therefore can't use .htaccess - I have to use rewrite.script instead).  Problem is, the paths that CKEditor puts into the head section of the page don't work, so the editor won't load.

For instance, one generated path is:

```
http://www.example.com/js/ckeditor/config.js?t=B8DJ5M3
```

If I go to

```
http://www.example.com/js/ckeditor/config.js
```

I can see the file, but as soon as I add the `?t=B8DJ5M3` on the end, Cake complains that it can't find the jsController.

I'm not sure what to do about this - whether to dig around in CakePHP, CKEditor or the rewrite.script files!  What should I try next?

Comment: Do you really need the parameter? If it is going to be always the same, you can try to add it directly inside a variable on the .js file.

Anyway, it should work with it... can you show us how you exactly load the .js file? Do you use the helper or you do it directly?

Comment: It seems like the query is just for caching, as was said in another comment.  So the value in it doesn't matter... the problem is coming from the fact that the query is there in the first place... the server is trying to read it as part of the file url.  Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query string on the end of your URL is used to make sure the file isn't cached. Seems like something in your GET request configuration/routing on the Zeus server is trying to locate that exact file including the query string. You're going to need to create a Rewrite that performs a goto on the URL minus the query string. I found a pretty solid article in the Drupal forums where someone put together a script that may help you: http://drupal.org/node/46508

```
RULE_0_START:
# get the document root
map path into SCRATCH:DOCROOT from /
# initialize our variables
set SCRATCH:ORIG_URL = %{URL}
set SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI = %{URL}

# see if theres any queries in our URL
match URL into $ with ^(.*)\?(.*)$
if matched then
  set SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI = $1
  set SCRATCH:QUERY_STRING = $2
endif
RULE_0_END:
```

And from there, handle your goto minus the query string. Hope that helps

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much - I've been tearing my hair out over that for weeks!

Comment: The bounty has expired - I've restarted it, but can't award it for 24 hours... will do that when I can!

Comment: Glad that worked! I worked with CKEditor once and I remember the source just being a complete nightmare

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

In the view where you want to display the editor, put the following script on the top of the page (or somewhere before textarea which you want to contain editor):

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('ckeditor/ckeditor');?>
```

This scipt will include the "webroot/js/ckeditor.js" file to your view.
Create the textarea and give it a class named "ckeditor"

```
<?php echo $this->Form->textarea('content',array('class'=>'ckeditor'))?>
```

Voila! The editor is now displaying instead of raw textarea.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the bit that's not working!  It does all that properly, but then when it tries to reference the file, it can't find it.